# Angular UI router structure for this type of application

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an reporting application that uses stacked tabs for navigation.  These tabs are in a parent/child hierarchy as shown below.

[image]

When the user selects the parent tab (ex feature 2) they the feature page which may or may not have sub-features.  If there are sub feature these are displayed as separate pages accessed via the subfeature tab.  The user selects parameters on the page, presses the Launch button, and an appropriate report is created.   When a feature or subfeature page is selected a MRU screen appears to the right with hyperlinks that will launch previous reports for the feature/subfeature.

Using Angular UI Router the hierarchy seems to be.

feature 1

- subfeature 1.1
- subfeature 1.2

feature 2

- subfeature 2.1
- subfeature 2.2

MRU - named view?

1. Is this a good case to use Angular-UI - router?
2. If so, does my hierarchy seem reasonable?  Or should there be a nav state that contains the feature/subfeature hierarchy.  That has some appeal since the nav page could host the feature tabs.
3. How can I reference the MRU list?  Is this a case for a "named" view?

This would be my first application using angular-ui-router so I appreciate any advice or relevant examples.

jerry

Comment: Do you want users to be able to bookmark their state in these sub views (tabs within)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by bookmark.  If you mean do I need the users to be able to return to tab away and return to the tab the controls have the exact original selections then that is not a requirement.  In fact a lot of the controls on the tabs are the same and I have a service that holds shares data so if a user changes a control values on one tab that change appears when they go another tab with the same control.

Comment: I think this URL covers ui-router usage quite well. http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-ui-router.html